# Undo an amendment of an older commit using a different branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, branching-and-merging

Suppose I've `git rebase`'d a branch `b2` of my repository, amending an older commit (`c1`). This commit exists, unamended, on another branch `b1` (and there are some more common commits on both branches after `c1`, then `b2` diverges from `b1`).

Now, I want to use to essentially undo my amendment to `c1` on `b2`. How should I do this, so that the two branches' history becomes maximally identical again?

Comment: Can you define "maximally identical"? Also, are the branches shared or not? Are they meant to be merged again? How? At which point? Help us understand the workflow here.

Comment: @RomainValeri: 1. Identical up to where they diverged, before the amendment. 2. They might well be merged in the future, yes. 3. Not telling you how or at which point... please don't make assumptions about the workflow. I just want to undo my amendment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `git rebase --onto`.  Specify the target with the `--onto` argument and specify the commits *not* to copy with the usual *`upstream`* argument.  It's hard to say from here exactly what those arguments should be; see the long discussion below.

#### Long

This requirement:

> ... that the two branches' history becomes maximally identical again

means that it becomes important that you know that `git rebase` works by *copying* commits.  For a quick recap of ideas let's note that:

- each commit has a unique hash ID;
- each commit holds a snapshot of all files; and
- each commit also holds some metadata.

The metadata in the commit include the author and committer and log message, but also—key to this whole process—the hash ID of the *parent* of the commit.

To turn a commit into a change-set, i.e., to find out what someone changed in any given commit, we have Git compare the commit to its parent.  The commit stores its parent's hash ID so `git show` or `git log -p` can find this on its own.

Meanwhile, a *branch name* like `b2` just holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.  So we can draw them—the commits and the branch names—like this:

```
... <-c1 <-c2 <-c3    <--b2
```

where each *c<sub>i</sub>* is an actual commit represented by its hash, and an arrow coming out of something means *points to:* the branch name `b2` points to commit `c3`, `c3` points to `c2`, `c2` points to `c1`, and so on.

Nothing about any commit can ever change so we can draw the internal arrows, from commit to commit, as connecting lines instead of arrows, as long as we remember that they're part of the child and point backwards to the parent.  This lets us draw, in crude text graphics, more than one branch.  I'll use `X1` and up as this is just an example, not exactly related to your starting point:

```
...--X1   <-- branch1
       \
        X2--X3   <-- branch2
```

If `branch1` acquires more commits, the newest eventually leads back to `X1`:

```
...--X1--X4--X5   <-- b1
       \
        X2--X3   <-- b2
```

Now back to your original setup:

> Suppose I've git rebase'd a branch `b2` of my repository, amending an older commit (`c1`). This commit exists, unamended, on another branch `b1` (and there are some more common commits on both branches after `c1`, then `b2` diverges from `b1`).

I'll draw as accurate a picture as I can of the original setup:

```
                    c4--c5   <-- b1
                   /
...--c0--c1--c2--c3
                   \
                    c6--c7   <-- b2
```

(I'm filling in missing details with guesses, though in the end the guesses should not matter much.)

When you ran `git rebase -i <start-point>` while on `b2` and amended/edited commit `c1`, Git had to *copy* `c1` to some new and different commit.  The new commit has an author and log message as usual, which were initially set up to be copied from `c1`, but it has a new and different hash ID and maybe a different snapshot and/or different log message (or even different author), depending on exactly what you changed.  Let's call the new copy `c1'` to tell them apart:

```
                    c4--c5   <-- b1
                   /
...--c0--c1--c2--c3
       \
        c1'  [copying in progress]
```

Because `c1` got copied to `c1'`, Git now was *forced* to copy `c2` to a new `c2'`:

```
                    c4--c5   <-- b1
                   /
...--c0--c1--c2--c3
       \
        c1'-c2'  [copying in progress]
```

The difference from `c1'` to`c2'` is the same as the difference from `c2` to `c1`.  That is, if we compare `c2` vs its parent `c1`, we'll get some set of changes.  If we compare `c2'` to `c1'`, we'll get the same *changes*, even if `c1` has different contents from `c1'`.

Now that `c2` is replaced with `c2'`, this forces Git to copy `c3` to `c3'` as well.  That forces Git to copy `c6` and `c7` too.  The final copied commit is `c7'` and `git rebase` finishes by yanking the *name* `b2` over, so that the final result is:

```
                    c4--c5   <-- b1
                   /
...--c0--c1--c2--c3--c6--c7   [old b2, now abandoned]
       \
        c1'-c2'-c3'-c6'-c7'  <-- b2 (HEAD)
```

> Now, I want to use to essentially undo my amendment to c1 on b2. How should I do this, so that the two branches' history becomes maximally identical again?

You may also have added even more commits since then:

```
                    c4--c5   <-- b1
                   /
...--c0--c1--c2--c3--c6--c7   [old b2, now abandoned]
       \
        c1'-c2'-c3'-c6'-c7'-c8--c9   <-- b2 (HEAD)
```

What you might like to end up with is:

```
                    c4--c5   <-- b1
                   /
...--c0--c1--c2--c3--c6--c7--c8'-c9'  <-- b2 (HEAD)
       \
        c1'-c2'-c3'-c6'-c7'-c8--c9   [abandoned]
```

It's probably OK (and usually a lot easier to *do*) if you end up with:

```
                    c4--c5   <-- b1
                   /
...--c0--c1--c2--c3--c6"-c7"-c8'-c9'  <-- b2 (HEAD)
```

with none of the abandoned commits drawn in.<sup>1</sup>

To get either of these, you want to:

- tell Git to copy at least `c8` and `c9` (assuming they exist), and
- tell Git to *not* copy `c1'` through `c3'`

and this means using `git rebase --onto`, so that you can separate two instructions that `git rebase` usually combines.

That is, what `git rebase` does is:

1. Enumerate some list of commits to copy.  In the example above, these were `c1` through `c7`.  If you use `git rebase -i`, the list goes into a modifiable instruction sheet using the word `pick` along with each commit's hash (shortened) and the subject line from the commit log message.

   Normally, *merge* commits—those with two or more parents—are ejected from the list right away.  (There are some modes that don't reject them; these are more complicated and we'll ignore them here.)

   Which commits get listed?  That's from your *`upstream`* argument: the commits to be *copied* are those that are reachable from `HEAD` by walking backwards, commit to commit: `c7` leads back to `c6`, which jumps back to `c3`, which goes back to `c2`, and so on.  But, from this list—which could go back a really long way—we *remove* any commits reachable from the *`upstream`* argument.  So if *`upstream`* is the hash ID of `c0`, we'll take `c0` *away* from the list, and also any commit before `c0`.  That means the list starts with `c1` and ends with `c7`, skipping the unreachable-this-way `c4` and `c5`.
2. Pick a target for `--onto`.  If you use `--onto`, you choose this directly.  If not, you choose it with your *`upstream`* argument.  For instance, with `git rebase master`, the upstream is `master` and the `--onto` target is the commit to which the name `master` points.  Git does a `git checkout --detach` here (or the internal equivalent) so as to get off the branch with the commits you're copying.
3. Begin copying commits, as if by `git cherry-pick`, one at a time.  Some rebase operations literally use `git cherry-pick` and some don't, quite.
4. When the copying is finished, move the original *branch name* so that it points to `HEAD`, which is the last copied commit, or—if we didn't copy any commits after all—the `--onto` target.  Then get back on that branch, as if by `git checkout name`.

Using `--onto` lets you change the *`upstream`* argument without also setting the target of the rebase.

So, if you want to copy *just* `c8` and `c9`, you can tell by inspection that the `--onto` target is `c7`, and that the first commit you *don't* want copied is `c7`.  This wouldn't require `git rebase --onto` after all.  If you have the hash ID of `c7` available, you could, for instance, run:

```
git rebase <hash-of-c7>
```

while on branch `b2`.  But to find the original `c7`, before the first rebase, you'll have to rummage through the reflogs.  This can be difficult, as the reflogs tend to contain a lot of motion, and once you've copied one commit once, you may have copied it many times.<sup>2</sup>

So we can instead just let Git copy `c6'` and `c7'` again.  We'll set the *`upstream`* to `c3'` as the first commit *not* to copy, and set `c3` as the `--onto` target:

```
git rebase --onto <hash-of-c3> <hash-of-c3'>
```

for instance.  Git will enumerate the commits by walking back from `HEAD` (`c9`) until it reaches `c3'`, which you said not to copy (nor anything earlier).  That will list `c6'`, `c7'`, `c8`, and `c9` as the commits to copy.  The copies are to go after `c3` (`--onto`).  Note that commits `c3` and `c3'` are both easily visible in the history and crude ASCII graph that Git draws that you can view with:

```
git log --graph --oneline b1 b2
```

so this gives you your hash IDs for the `--onto` and upstream arguments.

---

<sup>1</sup>`c9` and its abandoned history are all still there, in your Git repository, if you want them back later.  They can be found via Git's *reflogs*.  The reflog entries only last for some period of time.  After 1 to 3 months by default, the reflog entries expire, and are deleted.  Once that happens, the abandoned commits themselves can also be deleted for real, after which you *can't* get them back, at least not through your own Git.

(The details of reflogs and reflog expiration are a little complicated but not all that relevant here.)

<sup>2</sup>To view the reflog for branch `b2`, run `git reflog b2`.  If you're lucky, there's not a lot of copies and not a lot of random motion and you *can* find `c7` this way.